# How to launch SQL user defined procedure exclusively, without transaction, using external launcher.exe?

Tags: windows, azure-sql-database, exe

I am migrating the older application from on-premise "old and good" SQL server to Azure SQL. So far, so good.

The old solution used Job Agent to launch the `usp_data_pump` to get some data from 3rd party database. The first run (having my database empty) takes about 30 minutes. Because of added optimizations, the next runs take about 5 seconds when the watched data did not change in the other database. It can take more time, but--because of how the data are created--it will still be rather seconds. However, in some situations, the my database content can be "reset" (user action), and then it can again take those 30 minutes or so.

I need to pump the data each 5 minutes to get the minor changes.

As the Azure SQL does not have Job Agent, I have decided to use the near by Azure Windows Server and its standard Scheduler to execute `launcher.exe` every 5 minutes that just connects to the Azure SQL Server, executes the `usp_data_pump` stored procedure and stops. However, when the scheduler acts, it runs "forever".

I am not sure what happens. The first thought was that the `launcher.exe` was launched again after the 5 minutes when the previous did not finished its task, yet. However, in the Settings tab of the scheduled tasks the options is set...

> Do not start new instance

Firstly, how to implement periodical, exclusive execution of the `usp_data_pump` procedure. The transaction must not be used inside.

Comment: Logic Apps can execute stored procedures and have really flexible scheduling.

Comment: Is this document helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/job-automation-overview?

Comment: @LeonYue: Thanks, it could be helpful. I am fresh to Azure. When tranferring the solution, I tried to use the things that I know. Also, being the 3rd party, I have to make some trade-offs if the solution costs money.

Comment: Hi @pepr, The Elastic Job agent is free. The job database is billed at the same rate as any database in Azure SQL Database. I think you could think about that.  May I post it as answer?

Comment: @LeonYue Yes, please. I will accept it. Even though I am not sure (yet) if I will use it.

Comment: @pepr Thank you! I have posted it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL database has two auto jobs for us SQL agent for Azure MI and Elastic jobs for Azure SQL database  You can use the Elastic Jobs to execute your stored procedures.

Ref this document: [Automate management tasks using elastic jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/job-automation-overview):

- You can create and schedule elastic jobs that could be periodically
  executed against one or many Azure SQL databases to run Transact-SQL
  (T-SQL) queries and perform maintenance tasks.

The Elastic Job agent is free. The job database is billed at the same rate as any database in Azure SQL Database.

HTH.